# Korean isekai light novel. Male protagonist inhabits the villain's body and breaks off his engagement

Tags: story-identification, isekai

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a Korean light novel, where the male protagonist reincarnates/poses/transmigrates into the body of a villain and breaks off his engagement with his fiancee who the villain was very obsessed with in the original work, him as a villain He is hated for the actions his character performed in the past of the original work.

It's not any of the following;

no more pain for this villain (( https://www.lightsnovel.com/details/no-more-pain-for-this-villain-(5)-2079 ))

stuck as a villain (( https://www.scribblehub.com/series/624250/stuck-as-a-villain/ ))

a side villain (( https://www.scribblehub.com/series/525736/a-side-villain/ ))

I'm the lowly villain in the game (( https://www.scribblehub.com/series/496236/im-the-lowly-villain-in-the-game/ ))

erotic rpg i am in the game world, but my heroines are villainess (( https://www.lightsnovel.com/details/erotic-rpg-i-am-in-the-game-world-but-my-heroines-are-villainesses(8)-1935 ))

villain is on vacation (( https://www.lightsnovel.com/details/villain-is-on-vacation(9)-1996 ))

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: in December 2019 before the pandemic, at that time it had more or less 30 chapters, but since I had to move and change PCs, I don't have the chrome story and I've been looking for it again for about a month

Comment: Can you tell us anything more about the plot or characters? This isn't much to go on.

Comment: The villain is a useless nobleman with no talent in martial arts or magic, because the protagonist knows that even if he works hard he will not have enough strength, he decides to face his flags of death by avoiding the cause and as backup he carries equipment and skills used by others in the original plot The first thing is that in the main route and in others he dies when confronted by the hero for harassing his fiancée, to avoid this he stops harassing his fiancée and cancels the engagement,

Comment: on another route he dies when a beast girl confronts him for enslaving and killing several of his acquaintances from his hometown, he moves all his slaves to a border town on his lands and, with the excuse of avoiding other slave traders, does not frees them. He frees them from their seals of slavery but orders them to forget his past with him and try to live happily and comfortably in that town. If they require something they can move freely in their domains as long as they live there, when they go to the academy they like a mature teacher and I think I remember